# F5 TLM TypeError: Object of type Nodes is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, f5

Hi I am banging my head to understand why it not serializing into json (using json.dumps) as the output type for the node.raw is <class 'dict'>, please let me know if you can spot the stupidity in the code.

```
from f5.bigip import ManagementRoot
import json 

user = 'admin'
password = 'secret'
f5_ip = '10.0.0.10'
partition = 'PART1'


mgmt = ManagementRoot(f5_ip, user, password)
ltm = mgmt.tm.ltm

nodes = ltm.nodes.get_collection()

for node in nodes:
    node_dict = node.raw
    node_json = json.dumps(node_dict, indent=4)
    print(node_json)
```

Answer (score 0):

the raw output doesn't have a **dict** method or this would be an option for you. In [bigrest](https://bigrest.readthedocs.io/) (which I recommend over the f5-sdk for many reasons, mostly because it is still being actively developed even though not by f5 employees) the native behavior is the same, but because it does have that method, it works just fine:

```
from bigrest.bigip import BIGIP
b = BIGIP('10.0.2.15', 'admin', 'admin')
nodes = b.load('/mgmt/tm/ltm/node')
for node in nodes:
    print(json.dumps(node)) # FAILS -> TypeError: Object of type RESTObject is not JSON serializable

for node in nodes:
    print(json.dumps(node.__dict__)) # SUCCEEDS
```

If you open an issue on the [f5-sdk repo](https://github.com/F5Networks/f5-common-python), I'll run this by a few people to see if it's worth fixing, but no promises.

Comment: Thanks Json for the advise, I will give a shot to bigrest too, but I have raised an issue on the [f5-sdk repo](https://github.com/F5Networks/f5-common-python/issues/1580) for the feature request